Can I check which pods are writing to a pvc?
We have noticed that a big part of our monthly charges comes from EFS reads/writes. We know that this comes from our EKS cluster, but we would like to pinpoint which pods are the ones that are responsible for this.
Is there any way to do this?
We have tried to check from which pod the traffic is coming to the EFS, but through Cloudwatch we could only get from which node it is coming

you can add open telemetry to track application-based network traces and add NodeSelectors to your deployments so that solving issues like this can be easy for you in the future.

there is opensource tools also that gives you network cost based on labels.
